# Convert datetime format using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using ASP.NET3.5 with C# 2008 and I am novice to use `LINQ`. I have a `dataset` to which I am fetching table's data that includes a column with type `datetime`. Now, I want to convert this date in 24 hours format with Date and Hours, Minutes and seconds only. The stored date time is in 12 hours format. I have tried

```
ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(i => i["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(i["CreatedDate"].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

and then I am passing the `dataset` to `gridview` as a `datasource`.

It is not giving any exception but it is not converting the date into 24 hours format.

Can anyone help please. 
Awating for your valuable response..

Thank you,
Dev

Comment: _"The stored date time is in 12 hours format"_ No, the string which represents a `DateTime` is formatted, a `DateTime` never has a format. Use a `DateTime` when you store a `DateTime`, use a `string` only when you want to display it. If it's already a `DateTime` in your `DataSet` you don't need to convert it to a `string` and back to a `DateTime` via `Convert.ToDateTime(i["CreatedDate"].ToString())`.

Comment: What datatype is `CreatedDate`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just set the `DataFormatString` in the GridView.

Comment: I would have simply set the format on the binding to the column in the grid myself. Converting dates to strings in the source which is what are trying to do will cause you to have to convert it back to a date to any date operations on it.

Comment: I am simply fetching it from database, it is showing AM/PM.. I just want it in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

*"The stored date time is in 12 hours format"* No, the string which represents a `DateTime` is formatted, a `DateTime` never has a format. Use a `DateTime` when you store a `DateTime`, use a `string` only when you want to display it. If it's already a `DateTime` in your `DataSet` you don't need to convert it to a `string` and back to a `DateTime` via `Convert.ToDateTime(i["CreatedDate"].ToString())`.

This code is a  mess, sorry:

```
ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(i => i["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(i["CreatedDate"].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Why?

- You are converting a `DataTable` to a `List<DataRow>` although a `DataTable` is already a in-memory object. That is pointless and inefficient
- You are storing a `DateTime` as string, you can use `DateTime` as type for a `DataColumn` in a `DataTable`, convert it to a string at the very last stage when you want to display the value
- You are converting the "string-date" to a datetime, using `ToString` to format it as string and then you're converting it again to a datetime. This will use the default `ToString`(with your curentculture) to diplay it which is the reason why you don't get the desired format

So assuming that is's really a string and you don't want/can change it to `DataTime`, this might work:

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => Date.Parse(r.Field<String>("CreatedDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
gridView1.DataSource = query;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Note that you could also use the [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property of the GridView's `BoundField`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" 
                HeaderText="Created-Date" 
                SortExpression="CreatedDate" 
                DataFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

But then you need to store it as/convert it to a `DateTime` in the table and use that as `DataSource`.

Comment: Also  DataFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" displays the string "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" in column instead of date

Answer (score -1):

I hope It will work. You can try this one.

```
 ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(i => i["CreatedDate"] =    Convert.ToDateTime(i["CreatedDate"].ToString()).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Man.. Can you see my code I have posted above?? You just have removed date, nothing else. Please come out with some logical solutions